# Random extremely long request in Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a really strange behaviour in my Rails app.

Sometimes, like 1 request every 500, I have a simple ActiveRecord code which takes a lot of time (from 5 sec to X min). Some examples here:

```ruby
User.where(id: params[:id]).first # or
current_user # (with *Devise*) or
Authentication.where(provider: 'whatever', user_id: 12345).first
```

I don't really know where to look at: all these requests have appropriate indexes (they usually work in millisecond times), the server load seems constant, ...

Anyone here had this kind of issue before or some ideas on how I could resolve them?

Thanks!

*FYI, I work with Rails/ActiveRecord 3.2.17, puma 3.11.4, Docker (ECS on AWS), MySQL 5.6.34*

Comment: Seems like that is going to be an I/O issue I would look at the the tools AWS provides to see the load on the VM Image and MySQL when it hangs up.

Comment: First, thanks for your help.

MySQL seems OK : I don't see any peak in the different graphs provided by AWS (and I look "maximum" values only). In fact, by looking more requests, I've seen the same issue with non-active_record code.

Concerning the VM, the CPU never go above 30%. But maybe I'm not looking the correct data: what do you mean by "the load on the VM" ?

Comment: Does AWS show you memory consumption statistics? Also when this event occurs have you looked at the rails logs to see how long the queries/views took to load?

Comment: We have noticed some CPU overload (I'll check the memory tomorrow). If that's the case, what would you suggest to get rid of these memory pb? Maybe move problematic docker instances on other machines...

Comment: Honestly this is just diagnostics. Once you determine the issue then there can be a discussion as to resolution. Any idea how many users are accessing this site at any one time? What are the current specs for the machine vCores, Ram, etc. Is the database running on the same instance as the web server? If yes maybe separate the 2 if no then determine which machine is struggling.